# Почему появляется отступ в form?

Tags: html, css, html5, sass, style

Делаю все по пропорциям, все свойства правильные(не факт) и выходит отступ справа, хотя я его не задавал. Убрать тоже не получается

[image: HTML CODE]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отступы идут от contact-form
Все скрины предоставил) Кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Элементы `<input class="input-mobile">` и `<input class="input-email">` выравниваются по левому краю. Отступ между ними устанавливается автоматически, **но**. Оба элемента имеют свойства `width: 40%` и `width: 48%` соответственно. Отступ задается от родителя - `.contact-form`. 40% + 48% = 88%. Соответственно, "отступ" справа примерно равен этим 12%, которых не хватает в `.input-mobile` и `.input-email`. Просто задайте такую ширину элементов, чтобы в сумме они давали 100%, либо выравняйте эти элементы по центру формы. Для реализации второго варианта, можно просто добавить `.contact-form` свойство `justify-content: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-mobile {width = 40%;}
.input-email {width = 48%;}
```

40% + 48% = 88%. Ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: Не думаю, что намёк является хорошим ответом.

Comment: Если я делаю width немного больше, то формы уходят в два этажа, это кстати из за того отступа. Не думаю что стоит быть таким остроумным как вы